# Factor model for Gold has low adjusted R2

Tags: programming, time-series, regression, factor-models

I am trying to build up a factor model for gold. To be able to identify the correct factors, I did a correlation analysis between a few factors vs gold and I integrated this analysis with what I saw in literature. I ended up with a set of factors as: VIX Index, EURUSD currency, H15X10YR Index (which is the US 10YR real rate). However, after running my ridge regression (I choose ridge due to the fact that I had already an idea of the factors and they are only 3, otherwise in case of many factor and no idea I would opt for lasso), my adjusted R2 is "only" 36%..am I missing something? after checking the time history I see that the gold has quite a similar trend with my factors, especially with the H15X10YR Index, but my level of "explicability" is only 36%. Can anybody highlight me on the reason of this please? Luigi

Comment: Are you using past values of those factors to predict gold returns? Or using contemporaneous returns to just explain gold returns?

Comment: You should be careful in interpreting the $R^2$ as a measure of *explicability.*  It is very sensitive to a variety of things and the regularization implies it is no longer the square of the Pearson Product Moment Correlation Coefficient.  Since $R^2$ is  poor measure of goodness of fit and is not a measure of model quality, you should be careful in interpreting it or granting it too much importance.

Comment: @DaveHarris, thanks for highlight these aspects on R2. if not R2, what would you suggest to use to measure the explicability of a factor model? any other metrics? in terms of model quality I use purged with embargo cross validation for estimating the regularization parameter. thanks

Answer (score 2):

I will assume you are using factors and gold returns that are contemporaneous. With that setup, you are essentially trying to explain or decompose gold returns.

For an explanatory regression of a commodity (which is internationally traded), an $R^2$ of 36% is pretty good. Lots of factors can affect gold returns: Indian wedding season (a *major* effect on gold markets which you should not overlook), volatility in developing market currencies, and hyperinflation in large economies.  You are omitting all of those effects. To still explain 36% of the variance is something to be proud of.

You may have expected more, but working with returns reveals how explaining changes in an asset isn't as simple as just showing a few similar-looking plots and exclaiming *voila*! I would not be upset at getting a 36% $R^2$ for my first model and one using only three factors.

Comment: the returns I am using go from 2003 up to june 2020. Thanks for your answer. I am not indeed prone to look at how much the time histories are similar, cause I know the visual check can be misleading but this time was pretty evident they were similar. Anyway as you pointed out there may be many other factors which I kept out.